# Присвоить уникальный id

Tags: php, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как при нажатии на кнопку присвоить уникальный id в html тег

```
<p id="">Текст</p>
```

Исходный код

```
<textarea readonly id="txt" type="text" name="area" style="width:100%; height:300px; ">
<?php echo file_get_contents('textfile.txt') ?>
</textarea> <br>
<input class="btn btn-success mr-2" id="tx2" type="button" onclick='document.querySelector("textarea[name=area]").value+="<p class=\"dragElement txt\">" + document.getElementById("tx").value + "</p>"' value="Вставить текст"> &nbsp; <input id="tx" type="text" placeholder="Введите ваш текст">
```

Comment: Чтобы присвоить уникальный id - вы должны уникально идентифицировать этот tag - есть идеи как вы хотите это сделать?

Comment: @Axenow нужно присвоить для каждого тега свой id. <p id="<?php $a; ?>Текст</p> Было бы не плохо присваивать значение переменной $a. Значение переменной - время в мс.

Comment: Для каждого тэга на странице?
То есть вы сначала генерируете страницу, потом нажимаете на кнопку и каждый тэг получает уникальный id - правильно?

Comment: В данный момент я при нажатии на кнопку вставляю в текст в textarea. Кнопка вставить текст - вставляет <p>Текст</p>

Comment: А можно попросить добавить сюда ваш который, у вас есть? На его основе будет проще сделать то, о чем вы просите.

Comment: @Axenow вот часть кода, <textarea readonly id="txt" type="text" name="area" style="width:100%; height:300px; "><?php echo file_get_contents('textfile.txt') ?></textarea> <br>
      
      
<input class="btn btn-success mr-2" id="tx2" type="button" onclick='document.querySelector("textarea[name=area]").value+="<p class=\"dragElement txt\">" + document.getElementById("tx").value + "</p>"'  value="Вставить текст"> &nbsp; <input id="tx"  type="text" placeholder="Введите ваш текст"> сейчас вставляется тег без id, но нужно что бы был id с уникальным значением.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("tx2").onclick = function(){
   var timeStampInMs = Date.now();
   document.getElementById("txt").value +=
   "<p class=\"dragElement txt\" id=\""+timeStampInMs+"\">" + document.getElementById("tx").value + "</p>"
}
```

```html
<textarea readonly id="txt" type="text" name="area" style="width:100%; height:300px; ">
 <?php echo file_get_contents('textfile.txt') ?>
 </textarea> 
 <br> 
 <input class="btn btn-success mr-2" id="tx2" type="button" value="Вставить текст"> &nbsp; 
 <input id="tx" type="text" placeholder="Введите ваш текст">
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку на странице HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: А вы просто взяли и скопировали? Верхняя часть (первое окошко) это javascript. Его отдельно в <script> </script> засунуть. Нижняя часть это ваш Html. Заменить на то, что вы предоставили.

Comment: да, все получилось, спасибо большое.